# Excel file using PHP to work for Mac numbers and windows excel

Tags: php, excel, macos, numbers

I have created a simple script using PHP header by which I am creating excel document which is working fine for MS Excel in windows and MAC OS.

below is the code

```
<?php 
$Timestamp = date("d-m-Y");
header('Content-type: application/excel');                                  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Estimates-'.$Timestamp.'.xls"');
 <table class="table" width="800px">

   <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #666666; color:#ffffff; width:690px" align="left">Names</th>
    <th style="background-color: #666666; color:#ffffff; width:110px" >Bonus Amount</th>
   </tr>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td >Praveen Solanki</td>
    <td >45000</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Pramit Solanki</td>
    <td >30000</td>
   </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td >Ashish Surawanshi</td>
    <td >30000</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But when i open the same file in MAC machine using "**NUMBERS**" application, it is showing me my above html code. Because "NUMBERS" doesnt support this formatting which i found by R&D.

But now the question is how can i create the excel file which should work on **NUMBERS** plus MS EXCEL. 
As in my search i also found that the default document which i am creating directly form the **MS Excel** is currently opening on **NUMBERS**.

Looking for the correct path/code by which i can create the excel file.

Comment: Try using .csv, which is universal

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need excel file with style(s).